# Render A panel into div not working in ie9

Tags: extjs

I am trying to render an `Ext.Panel` into an html `div`. It is working in Firefox but in IE9 the panel does not show.

This is the panel :

```
Ext.onReady(function(){ 
    tabpanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
        activeTab: 0,
        deferredRender:false,
        items: [
            {
                title : '${tr.File}',
                items : [
                    fileTlb
                ]
            },
            {
                title: '${tr.Edit}',
                items : [
                    editTlb
                ]
            },
            { 
                title: '${tr.Review}'
            }
        ]
    });

    panel = new Ext.Panel({
        title : '${tr.EverSuiteViewer}',
        renderTo: 'tlbr'
    });

});
```

And The html div :

```
<div id="tlbr" style="height:13%;">

</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the console in IE9? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: yea , there are no errors